# Read array from file separated with commas and newlines

Tags: arrays, shell, csv

I have a file that has two different words per line, delimited by a comma and a line break. How can you read this file and store every word in an array? My code doesn't work because I think only works for "one line" array.

**File Sample:**

Each word is separated by a comma and a line break.

```
Dog,cat
shark,rabbit
mouse,bird
whale,dolphin
```

**Desired input**

```
"${array[0]}" = Dog
"${array[1]}" = cat
"${array[2]}" = shark
"${array[3]}" = rabbit
"${array[4]}" = mouse
"${array[5]}" = bird
"${array[6]}" = whale
"${array[7]}" = dolphin
```

**My Code:**

```
input=$(cat "/path/source_file")
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$input"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IFS=$'\n,' read -d '' -ra array < file
```

The key is to use `IFS` to tell `read` to split the entire input) `-d ''`) into array elements (`-a`; `-r` ensures unmodified reading) by both `\n` and `,` characters.

For simplicity, I've used `file` to represent your input file and used it *directly* as input to `read` via stdin (`<`).

If you do have a need to read the entire file into a shell variable first, the following form is slightly more efficient in Bash (but is not POSIX-compliant):

```
input=$(< "/path/source_file")
```

Answer (score 0):

Input Format:

Read the inarr1 from line 1 with array elements separated by (,) comma.

Read the inarr2 from line 2 with array elements separated by (,) comma.

Read the input from the standard input stream

Output format:

Comment: Can you provide code for that?